# How to fix Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock-map

I imported GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock eclipse project and encountered

> Error:Execution failed for task ':googleMapsV2:processDebugManifest'.
>    Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=() from
>   [GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock:androidmapsutils:unspecified]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:8:13-29   is also present at
>   [com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.2]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:20:66-119
>   value=(@integer/google_play_services_version).    Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:6:9-8:32 to override.

Is anybody has a clue on what it is and how can I fix it?

Here are the list of the errors.

googleMapsV2 build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':androidmapsutils')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
}
```

androidmaputils build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
}
```

GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

PagerTabSlidingTabStrip build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

Comment: change minSdkVersion to 14 in build.gradle

Comment: I have 4 build.gradle file and the only build.gradle file I have is         minSdkVersion 8

Comment: change 8 to 14 it will work

Comment: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 14. This occurs your problem . So change your minSdkVersion =14.

Comment: `Error:Execution failed for task ':googleMapsV2:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=() from [GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock:androidmapsutils:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:8:13-29
 is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:20:66-119 value=(@integer/google_play_services_version).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:9-8:32 to override.`

Comment: Can you paste your build.gradle file code here? It seems like some of the dependencies that you are using has a + in it for supporting the latest version of that library, without you having to make the changes in your build.gradle file.

Comment: Hi, pls. see above updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your build.gradle(app) `minSdkVersion 14` and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
```

Comment: Here I am having another error

`Error:Execution failed for task ':googleMapsV2:processDebugManifest'.
 Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.android.support:support-.v4:25.2.0] .C:\Users\rtyJa\Desktop\GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock\googleMapsV2\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support->v4\25.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml
 Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4" to force usage`

Comment: as you mention above you have 4 build.gradle then check every gradle file and set according to requirement

Answer (score 0):

add `tools:replace="android:value"` to your manifest to the end of `<application>` tag

Comment: Hi, where do I put those?

Comment: @JaysonJohn add tools:replace="android:value" to your manifest to the end of <application> tag

Comment: Please put a bit more effort into explaining your answer.

Comment: I am not seeing <application> tag. I put  the build.gradle files above . pls. check

Comment: manifest is not a gradle. Usually you declare your activities and services inside of this tag.
check this reference (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)
It should look like 
 `<application
.....
       tools:replace="android:value">`

Comment: Getting this Error now:
 tools:replace specified at line:13 for attribute android:value, but no new value specified
C:\Users\palfonso\AndroidStudioProjects\Match4App\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
 Validation failed, exiting